# How to add a vertex in bidirectional graph?

Tags: boost, graph, vertex, bidirectional

I'm using boost for an algorithm. However, its bidirectional graph seems to have no way to add a vertex. How could I initialise a MUTABLE bidirectional graph so that I can add vertices at any time?

Comment: Can't you use [MutableGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/MutableGraph.html)? Also it would be great if you show at least some pseudocode (or existing code if you have one) for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I see that. Problem temporarily closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see what the problem is: use the [expressions listed in the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/MutableGraph.html)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46efcc55d032b8fe)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS>;

#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp> // for display

int main() {
    Graph g;
    auto a = add_vertex(g);
    auto b = add_vertex(g);

    add_edge(a,b,g);

    print_graph(g);
}
```

Prints

```
0 --> 1 
1 -->
```

Comment: I think I need to have a try. The problem is temporarily closed.